# Whitespace woes in Regex

Tags: regex, perl, whitespace

I am using a simple Perl script to parse XML and convert it to usable SQL. My current SQL lines go something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('data1', 'data2', 'data3', );
```

Obviously I need to remove the comma at the end there. Sounds simple but I just can't get regex to find it. I tried `s/,\s+\)/\)/` but that doesn't change anything when I run it. Strangely, `s/,\s+/WTF/` doesn't modify anything either, when it should be replacing all the commas and the spaces next to them. BUT when I run `s/\s+\)/something/` it correctly finds and replaces the close parentheses at the end of the line. So apparently the whitespace character right after the commas is some strange ghost character that I can't find by any means. Not even with the `.` expression.

What's really weird though is when I use Find on the document in Notepad++ with the Regular Expression option, it finds all of them perfectly when I enter `,\s+\)` yet the exact same sequence in Perl regex will not find them.

I suspected it was something with `\r` (I'm using Windows) since I previously removed the `\n` characters but it won't find a `\r` in the whole sql file.

Thank you in advance for your help this is really puzzling me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off,

```
$ perl -E 'my $foo = "bar, baz"; $foo =~ s/,\s+/WTF/; say $foo'
barWTFbaz
```

It does work. (For perl 5.8 and before, change that to -e and `print "$foo\n"`)

Second, you're doing it wrong. Instead of doing something like:

```
$values = "'$values[0]', ";
$values .= "'$values[1]', ";
⋮
```

you should do:

```
$values = join(q{,}, map("'$_'", @values)); # map adds 'quotes'; join adds commas
```

Third, you shouldn't even do that, you should use placeholders:

```
# note specifying the column names, its a good idea! Schema change.
my $query = "INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?,?,?)";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute(@values);
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this expression:

```
s/,\W+)/)
```